# Redirecting ? with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I'm trying to redirect "somepage?open=support" to "support", I did this:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^open=support$

RewriteRule (.*) /support? [R=301,L]

But it works only works for some cases like:  "site.php?1=2?open=support" but not for "?1=2?open=support".

I want it to work for every & all cases.

Appreciate any advice on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

By putting `^` and `$` in your `RewriteCond` you are effectively saying query string must equal `open=support`. But sounds like you want *contains* `open=support`. So something like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(|.*\&)open=support(|\&.*)$
```

NOTE: I don't get the double `?`s in your examples at all, so ignoring them. But if you're allowing `?` to act as a delimiter in your query string like `&`, then maybe

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(|.*[\?\&])open=support(|[\?\&].*)$
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I add $ at the end as I only care for the url beginning. I need it to redirect all urls ending with " ?open=support " no matter what's before. Any ideas ?